# Get the position of the right interval

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of intervals:

```
Intervals = {{0, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}}
```

and a list of measurements:

```
Measurements = {0.1`, 3.2`, 2.5`, 1.4`, 5.8`, 5.9`}
```

Now I would like to get the position of the interval which contains the measurement. The following code is working perfectly:

```
Map[(temp = #; 
   First@Flatten@
     Position[Map[(IntervalMemberQ[Interval[#], temp]) &, Intervals], 
      True]) &, Measurements]
```

Nevertheless I find the Nestd Map construction not very compelling. Are there any ideas to solve this problem more elgantly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Flatten[Position[Intervals, x_ /; IntervalMemberQ[Interval[x], #], 
    2] & /@ Measurements]
```

Answer (score 2):

`IntervalMemberQ` accepts lists as arguments (either):

```
IntervalMemberQ[Interval /@ Intervals, #] & /@ Measurements // Position[#, True] & // #[[All, 2]] &
```

Comment: +1 but may I suggest `Flatten[Position[IntervalMemberQ[Interval /@ Intervals, #], True] & /@
   Measurements]`

Answer (score 2):

```
Last /@ Position[
  Thread[IntervalMemberQ[Interval /@ Intervals, #]] & /@ Measurements,
   True]
```

Comment: After multiple tests on the various solutions proposed here (I have personally tested the proposed solutions of Algohi, kguler, ect..). I think your solution is the best.  
Indeed, it is more robust and solves problems like :
`Intervals = {{0, 1}, {1, 2}, {0, 2}, {1.5, 2}};`  
`Measurements = {1, 2, 1.5};`  

For my part, I added :  
`Yourfun[Intervals, {#}] & /@ Measurements`  
For more clarity in the case of multiple inclusions.

Comment: doedalos@Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming only that the intervals are sorted.

```
intervals = {{0, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}};
measurements = {0.1`, 3.2`, 2.5`, 1.4`, 5.8`, 5.9`};

Map[Function[m,
  Length@TakeWhile[First /@ intervals, m > # &]],
 measurements]
```

> {1, 4, 3, 2, 6, 6}

or

```
Map[Function[m,
  Count[First /@ intervals, _?(m > # &)]],
 measurements]
```

> {1, 4, 3, 2, 6, 6}

Answer (score 1):

```
f1 = Function[{k},  Min[Length[#],
                        1 + LengthWhile[ Interval /@ #, ! IntervalMemberQ[#, k] &]]] /@ #2 &;

f1[intervals, measurements]
(* {1, 4, 3, 2, 6, 6} *)
```

or

```
Function[{is, ms},  Min[Length[is], 
                        1 + LengthWhile[Times @@@ Subtract[is, #], Positive]] & /@ ms];
f2[intervals, measurements]
(* {1, 4, 3, 2, 6, 6} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for variety (for strictly enclosed):

```
intervals = {{0, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}};
measurements = {0.1`, 3.2`, 2.5`, 1.4`, 5.8`, 5.9};
```

So,

```
fun[i_, m_] := Pick[i, Sign[# - m] == {-1, 1} & /@ i]
rul = Thread[intervals -> Range[Length@intervals]];
```

then,

```
(Join @@ fun[intervals, #] & /@ measurements) /. rul
```

yields

```
(*{1, 4, 3, 2, 6, 6}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
IntervalMemberQ[Interval /@Intervals, #] & /@ Measurements //Position[#, True] & // #[[All, 2]] &
```

Here I take the example of @Aisamu and reduce some postfix to make it a little clear.

```
 （#[[All，2]]&）@（Position[Map[IntervalMemberQ[Interval /@Intervals，#]&，Measurements]，True]）
```